# polynomial regression plot predicted value

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, linear, polynomial

I made a plot of a polynomial regression model with predicted y values on the y-axis and x on the x-axis. With the original data also on the plot, I can visualize my model. However, with this particular dataset, I can see 2 lines for the predicted values. See below:

[image]

Here's the code for my model:

```
fit <- lm(y~ poly(x2,2), data = data1)
pred1 <- predict(fit, data = data1)
plot(x2, y, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
lines(x2, pred1, lwd = .1, col = "blue")
```

Did I do something wrong here? I would imagine it will be a single curve line for the predictions.

Comment: What happens when you replace your second line of code with the following?

   pred1 <- predict(fit, data = data1, interval="none")

Comment: I still see 2 blue lines. My dataset is consisted of uniformly distributed x's and about 40 values of y's

Comment: This is a duplicate of several questions at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is arising from your call to the predict function. I think it must be something about how `predict()` handles models with polynomial terms --- I'm not quite sure why it's grouping it into multiple lines, but I do know how you can fix it.

If you specify `newdata` for the predict function instead of relying on the original data used for the fit, you should get a curve like you were expecting. Here's an example, using the `mtcars` data. First, I'll replicate your problem.

```
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ poly(qsec, 2), data = mtcars)
pred <- predict(fit1)
plot(mpg ~ qsec, data = mtcars)
lines(mtcars$qsec, y=pred, col = "blue")
```

This gives the multiple line result, like you found:
[image]

Instead, create a new dataframe to feed `predict`. Here, I'm using the full range of the predictor variable, stepping in a sequence from its min to its max by .01

```
newdata <- data.frame(qsec=seq(min(mtcars$qsec), max(mtcars$qsec), .01))
newdata$pred1 <- predict(fit1, newdata)
plot(mpg ~ qsec, data = mtcars)
lines(newdata$qsec, newdata$pred1, col = "red")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use ggplot2 for the plotting instead, where you won't face this strange issue.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x=qsec)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = .5) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,2))
```

[image]

**One other random note on the poly() function:**

Many people don't realize that its defaults produce polynomial trend contrasts, rather than polynomial terms of a continuous variable for polynomial regression. You'll notice the difference if you examine the regression coefficients from your model. Compare them to a model where you build the polynomial terms by hand (i.e. actually create a squared version of your `x2` variable to add as a predictor to the model along with `x2`) and you'll see.

If you want polynomial terms instead of contrast codes, you need to use `raw = TRUE` when you call `poly()`. See `?poly` for more information.

Comment: The problem is just the sorting of x values: Use `lines(sort(mtcars$qsec), y=pred[order(mtcars$qsec)], col = "blue")` in your first example.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use lines(), but stick with the predicted values alone:

```
data(mtcars)
with(mtcars, plot(mpg,wt))
lines(predict(lm(wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars)))
```

A ggplot2 solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt))+
+ geom_point()+
+ geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the issues for polynomial regression.